# Keep BG video from reloading on WP site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, video

I'm wondering if anyone has any info on how I might keep a fullscreen background video playing throughout my site without reloading every time a link is clicked. My site is http://armandwho.com/site

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Joe

Comment: I would say there are two options, you could either get the time position of the video when users click a link and set the video at that time when the page loads, or you could do all your requests with AJAX... Either way it's not going to be easy I think.

Comment: Thanks @MarioDeSchaepmeester ! I used your AJAX advice and found a great plugin that does exactly what I need.

Comment: are you sure the plugin will cover all your needs?